# DDD Topic - Lesson association AggregateRoot

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I'm new in DDD. I have a *Topic* entity and *Lesson* entity. *Topic* has many *Lessons*.
I need to add/remove *Topics* as well as *Lessons*. Should i create two different repositories for entities,
or just one TopicRepository which handles all the lessons? Is this a classic *Order - OrderItem* model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both entites makes sense without eachother, then go for the two different repositories.

If you delete a topic, should you then delete all lessons associated with this topic?
If, yes .. then You got yourself a TopicRepository handling both topics and lessons.

If no, you have two repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Do `Lesson`s make any sense without `Topic`s? if not, then yes, this is very much like *Order - OrderItem*.

Comment: It make sense, eventually users only care about the lessons, but a Topic is required for every Lesson